# Factorial number printing

Tags: python

I'm a newbie at python. I started it not long a ago as a hobby after uni lecture hours.

I found this exercise ( forgot where I got it from now) to do which is to print out the factorial numbers.

Which I did. But, problem is that I'm tasked to manipulate line 3 so it only prints out the number 1 once at the start of the sequence and I'm having trouble with that.

Please can any help? :)

In advance sorry if the question wasn't worded as good as it could have been.

```
a, b = 0, 1
while a < 19:
    print b,
    a, b = a + 1, b * (a+1)
```

Result:

> 1 1 2 6 24 120 720 5040 40320 362880 3628800 39916800 479001600 6227020800 87178291200 1307674368000 20922789888000 355687428096000 6402373705728000

Comment: Can you fix your code? Don't use `>>>` for code blocks, instead use 4 spaces in front of your lines of code. An easy way to format your code is to highlight your code and hit `ctrl`+`k`

Comment: Which one is line 3? `print b,` or `a, b = a + 1, b * (a+1)`?

Comment: Line 3 is the "print b," I just don't know how to change it so it only prints out 1 once in the sequence of numbers below. And thanks fro the tip!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a, b = 0, 1
while a < 19:
    if a: print b,
    a, b = a + 1, b * (a+1)
```

Use a in-line if statement to check if a is `1`. If it's `1` then you know that you already went through the loop at least once.

Comment: If your question is answered please consider accepting an answer to close the question.